# After adding a feature in the line layer , The line created is not visible even after changing the properties

Tags: qgis

[image]
I am a beginner at using gis. I am facing problems while creating line layer. After creation of layer when I try to edit the line drawn is not visible as it is never drawn. Although in attributes table all the attributes are saved

Comment: Could be a CRS (Coordinate Reference System) issue where your layers and the project do not match. Or your lines are hidden behind the raster layer.